# color dialog box

Tags: c#, colors, color-picker

I need to get the colors which added in custom color box in colordialog window.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you are asking for, can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 3):

[ColorDialog.CustomColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog.customcolors.aspx) property

[Here's an example of how to use it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/19cf2bdd-7e97-4642-8272-a125fb668179/)